# Why does my raspberry pi give an error after trying to install a package with pip?

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install a package on my raspberry py while using an SSH connection in the cmd but when I try to install one it give me this error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/pythonprojects $ sudo pip3 install guizero


Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x753afb80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution')': /simple/guizero/
```

It repeats that for a couple of times untit it gives up and gives me this error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement guizero
ERROR: No matching distribution found for guizero
```

I've tried the same thing with other packages and it does the same.

Comment: It implies (to me) that your DNS is not set correctly in your networking. Maybe check like this https://www.tecmint.com/find-my-dns-server-ip-address-in-linux/

Comment: You can also try to `ping pypi.org` to check if DNS is working